# What does exec(text) do?

Tags: security, postgresql-9.3, functions, amazon-rds

I just found the following function in two RDS PostgreSQL 9.3 DBs:

```
--
-- Name: exec(text); Type: FUNCTION; Schema: public; Owner: adam
--

CREATE FUNCTION exec(text) RETURNS text
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $_$ BEGIN EXECUTE $1; RETURN $1; END; $_$;


ALTER FUNCTION public.exec(text) OWNER TO adam;
```

I am pretty sure I did not write this function, and since `exec` seems like a security hazard (does it simply execute commands?) It would like to know what is it all about. Searching the method signature didn't help me.

**What does this function do?

Is it a security risk of some sort?

Which program/framework might have created it?**

Comment: "*What does this function do?*" - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a totally pointless function that executes arbitrary SQL. It isn't `SECURITY DEFINER` so the only risk I think it can pose is if you allow users to run arbitrary SQL predicates or call arbitrary functions (in which case you're probably already stuffed) but try to block them from running any command they want.

As you guessed, it just executes the SQL input using PL/PgSQL's dynamic SQL facilities.

Oh, it'd also hide the statement text from simple `log_statement` analysis, `auto_explain` etc, as they only look at top level statements, not statements run via PL/pgSQL.

Personally I'd drop/rename it, and see what complains.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Have you ever encountered a spontaneous creation of this function?

Comment: No. Something, or someone, created it. If you keep `log_statement = 'all`' logs far enough back you might be able to find out more.